# After creating a new record, I can't get my form to display it in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

StackOverflow. I have an issue I've been grappling with for too long. Currently, I have a form that displays consortium data, with a button that says "Create new consortium." When I click it, it shows a pop up window that allows you to enter the name, as displayed in the image below. Almost everything works fine, except I can't get it to display the new record after I create it. See my code below--you'll get a sense of what I'm trying to do.

By the way, if it matters, the "Consortium name" combo box allows you to select records. I don't see how it could throw my update off, but I thought I should include that information.

Here's the form:

[image: My form]

Here's the code:

[image: My code]

Interestingly, StackOverflow doesn't seem to indent the code properly after making an edit--I was able to do it successfully with a new test post. Oh well. I'm a noob to this as well:

```
Private Sub CreateConsortiumButton_Click()
    If IsNull(Me.ConsortiumNameText) Or Me.ConsortiumNameText = "" Then ''insert better validation here
        MsgBox "Please enter a valid consortium name."
    Else
        '' Create a new Consortium record with the ConsortiumNameText field on the popup window
        Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
        Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Consortium")
        rst.AddNew
        rst("Consortium name").Value = Me.ConsortiumNameText
        ConsortiumID = rst("ConsortiumID").Value
        rst.Update
        '' Now, create a corresponding record in the ResearchContributions table
        Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("ResearchContributions")
        rst.AddNew
        rst("ConsortiumID").Value = ConsortiumID
        rst.Update
        MsgBox "Consortium " & Me.ConsortiumNameText & " successfully created."
        '' Change the form's combo box to reflect the new record
        Forms!Main!NavigationSubform!ConsortiumNameCombobox = Me.ConsortiumNameText
        '' Close popup
        DoCmd.Close
        '' Attempt to set the record on the main form to the newly created one - NOT WORKING!
        DoCmd.OpenForm "Main", acNormal, , "[ConsortiumID] = " & ConsortiumID
    End If
End Sub
```

I think part of the issue may have to do with the fact that I've placed the "Consortium Form" form, which is based around a tab control, into the "Main" form. Perhaps because I'm trying to open the *Main* form with a certain ConsortiumID, that ConsortiumID doesn't apply to *Consortium Form*. It appears as though I can't link the master with its child, but this hasn't been necessary in the past. Please forgive me if the concepts sound vague in confused, for it is only because the concepts are vague and confused as of yet in my mind--this is my first Access project. Anyone have any tips?

Comment: What is the point of a picture of the code?

Comment: When I pasted the other text, it didn't do highlighting. I feel it would be more readable this way. If you prefer, I can paste the code.

Comment: I did it, but it mysteriously is not indenting properly after doing an edit. It can indent properly when I create a new post. Weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I think I figured it out. I've added the following code:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "Main"
DoCmd.Requery
DoCmd.SearchForRecord , , acFirst, "[ConsortiumID] = " & ConsortiumID
```

First, open the form, then requery in able to register the fact that the new item is in the database, then use SearchForRecord to open it up. Neato. Thanks, everyone.